# Web hosted site is different to html file

Tags: html, css, format, web, web-hosting

I am trying to make my first published site at the moment, and there is 2 main problems that i have come across and am yet to find a solution for. The weird thing is that running the file straight from the computer, it is completely fine and everything is how it should be. However, when i upload the files to the webhost service, running on the internet, it somehow loses its formatting.
Problem 1: The navbar is no longer spaced out and as large as it should be.
Problem 2: The image in the bottom left is no longer fixed to the corner.

Raw code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=143mKzs2_rabS4fuNRp3D8vC1jddY7wRb
(see the image named 'real' to see how it is meant to look)

Site: http://www.design-tabs-creative.co.uk/index.html

Comment: Just checked, it's working fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Try clearing your cache

Answer (score 0):

000webhost.com injects some custom javascript into web pages for displaying ads. It is very much possible that the injected javascript is conflicting with your HTML/CSS.

P.S.: I tried opening your link, it seemed to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I put the css code directly in the html files and it is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a css issue. Did you check that you uploaded all your css files and referenced them properly?
Go into inspect mode and take a look at your console to make sure there are no errors.